# How to remove a specific key form a string in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I need to remove a specific key suffixed or prefixed with underscore from a string and need to store the new string to a variable. This key might be present at start of the string or end of the string or in between with underscore and the string may contain special characters

```
String              Result
AA_B_676.csv.gz     AA_B.csv.gz
676_AA_B.csv.sgnl   AA_B.csv.sgnl
AA_B.csv_676        AA_B.csv
AA_B.csv.sgnl_676   AA_B.csv.sgnl
```

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, **no images**) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Hi Cyrus,    Desired out is mentioned in the Result column

Comment: That's still an image. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: I tried options like    var=`echo $string | sed "s/_\$676\././"`    but it is not working for the case .csv_676

Comment: Hi Cyrus, I would like to get a sed command which work for all the cases mentioned in the question

Comment: `sed -E 's/_676|676_//g'` ? Matches both `_676` and `676_`, replaces them with the empty string, multiple times a line if needed. It takes care not to change `A_676_B` into `AB` but rather `A_B`.

Comment: Thanks Aaron..This is working when I specify the key directly. But my key would present in a variable key and i updated the command like var=`echo $string | sed -E "s/_\$Key\|\$Key\_//"` , but not getting the expected result. $string is the string to be renamed

Comment: `the expected result` - what is the expected result? Can you post more input and output examples?

Comment: string=AA_B.csv.sgnl_676_done,  
      loadKey=676,  
      var=`echo $string | sed -E "s/_\$loadKey\|\$loadKey\_//"`        This is the code snippet i have. This should work for all the cases mentioned in the question

Comment: Hi Aaron, Can you please update the code provided with a variable key and the sed command should work if Key replaces with any number..Thanks a lot

Comment: I just saw your comments, you should use `@` mentions otherwise we get no notification. In your `sed` command the `$` shoudln't have been escaped : `$loadKey` expands to the content of the "loadKey" variable, `\$loadKey` expands to the `$loadKey` text. Using `${var/pattern/replace}` is a good idea though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use variable substitution:

```
${var/pattern/replace}
```

**example**

```
#!/bin/bash

testdata=(
AA_B_676.csv.gz
676_AA_B.csv.sgnl
AA_B.csv_676
AA_B.csv.sgnl_676
)

for str in "${testdata[@]}"; do
   str="${str/_676/}"
   str="${str/676_/}"
   echo "$str" 
done
```

**output**

```
AA_B.csv.gz
AA_B.csv.sgnl
AA_B.csv
AA_B.csv.sgnl
```